# Jmeter - Run sample multiple times based on regular expression extractor

Tags: regex, loops, while-loop, jmeter

I need to run a HTML request multiple times based on a regular expression extractor applied on the same request. I have put the HTML request under while controller however, I am stuck with writing the correct javascript code in while controller.

[image]

Here is the while controller code: `${__javaScript("${uidvalue}"=="test")}`.

I want the loop to end as soon as a uidvalue from the regular expression extractor is found. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your questions correctly, you want to keep on executing one request until response contains specific text.
I am able to do that by using JMeter's while controller.

1. Add While Controller to Test Plan.
2. Add request and Put Counter (Add-> Config Element-> Counter)
   [Please find following image 1 for reference of Counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NNeH.png)
3. Put condition in While Controller following:
   **${__groovy(("${Status}"!="Success") && ${count} <= 5)}**
   Always use count to repeat request and avoid JMeter to go in infinite loop.Here I am waiting for 'Success' status and executing request 5 times only.
   [Please find following image 2 for reference of While loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Yvl.png)

Thank you, I hope this helps.